# Why does adding this new XElement try to change the structure of the XML document?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

They say a man with one watch knows what time it is and a man with two is never sure. When it comes to the options using XML I seem to have a drawer full of them.

For what it's worth I'm using .Net 4.

I replaced my original code with a simplfied test write function with the generated XML string embedded as a comment.

I'm trying to add a new `UserVar` node to the sample XML below. The XML is from a commercial program and I do not have any input towards its design.

When I try to add the new entry I get an exception at the end during the `xDoc.Save()`

> This operation would create an incorrectly constructed document.

In theory I'm creating an XElement that contains children that match the structure of the original and trying to add it to the existing document. From other questions and examples this appears what is being done by others.

My code is below the XML. The function creates an XElement to be added to the document.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application>
  <Vars>
    <UserVars>
      <UserVar>
        <Name>"Quantity"</Name>
        <Width>4</Width>
        <VarValue>"1"</VarValue>
      </UserVar>
      <UserVar>
        <Name>"Printers"</Name>
        <Width>255</Width>
      </UserVar>
      <UserVar>
        <Name>"Changed"</Name>
        <Width>1</Width>
      </UserVar>
      <UserVar>
        <Name>"Weight"</Name>
        <VarValue>"450.1"</VarValue>
      </UserVar>
    </UserVars>
  </Vars>
</Application>
```

Code

```
public static void TestWriteData(string xmlDocNm)
{
  // Write a test value to an Acme UserVar in the exisiting XML
  var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlDocNm); //This is your xml path value 

  XElement xVar = new XElement("UserVar");

  // In this company's XML the strings have double quotes around them
  xVar.Add((new XElement("Name", "\"Title\"")));
  xVar.Add(new XElement("VarValue", "\"Paradise Lost\""));

  XElement xElement = new XElement("Application",
    new XElement("Vars",
    new XElement("UserVars",
    xVar)));

  // XML Data in xElement - String data copied from the IDE watch
  //<Application>
  //  <Vars>
  //    <UserVars>
  //      <UserVar>
  //        <Name>"Title"</Name>
  //        <VarValue>"Paradise Lost"</VarValue>
  //      </UserVar>
  //    </UserVars>
  //  </Vars>
  //</Application>

  xDoc.Add(xElement);
  xDoc.Save(xmlDocNm); //Write the XML back to the file
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here. It looks like you really should be able to come up with a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem in a lot less code. Also, it looks like you're avoiding the idiomatic exception approach to error, instead making all your methods return a "success" value. I'd *strongly* urge you to follow .NET idioms instead - it'll make your code a *lot* simpler.

Comment: My guess is you're adding multiple root elements to the document. It can contain only one root element.

Comment: @flup I'm including the same name as the root in the file in the case `Application`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I've somehow never heard the phrase .Net idiom before.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @RichShealer: It's not a particular phrase - it's just "the idioms of .NET".

Comment: I've changed the code section to directly add some data. With @davmos's answer the code does what I need it to. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is trying to add a second root element.

Change the line `xDoc.Add(xElement);` 
to `xDoc.Root.Element("Vars").Element("UserVars").Add(xElement);`

But before that, remove the code where you are creating the `<Application>` element. Just create/output the `<UserVar>` element.

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete picture. That works well.